# How do I generate Javadocs from Java in a cross-platform way?

Tags: java, clojure, javadoc, leiningen, build-tools

I'm working on improving the `lein-javadoc` plugin to the Leiningen build tool. It runs in a JVM process and has the project's classpath at its disposal. What is the most cross-platform way of generating javadocs?

1. Find `$JAVA_HOME/../lib/tools.jar` and include it on the plugin's classpath, then call `com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main`. (Old approach.)
2. Find `$JAVA_HOME/../lib/tools.jar` and construct a call to `java -cp path/to/tools.jar:rest:of:project:classpath com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main -javadoc -options -here`. (New approach.)
3. Call `javadoc` and pass it the options.

<del>Choice 3 sounds right in retrospect and I only discovered it after realizing that OpenJDK doesn't have tools.jar.</del> [Actually, it does! I only had the JRE packages installed for that version -- the JDK package does have tools.jar.]

However, before I rework the code to use that, are there any tradeoffs I should know about? Examples:

- Does calling javadoc make things harder on Windows? (Do I have to sniff out that it's Windows and call javadoc.exe instead?)
- Am I likely to encounter problems shelling out to one version of java (whatever's on the shell PATH) and using a different version's tools.jar (the version of the current JVM)?

Comment: Did you check what other build tools like maven, gradle or ant do it?

Comment: Hmm, good idea. I'll take a look around.

Comment: Looks like Maven locates javadoc or javadoc.exe and calls it. Seems kind of involved.